# Stepping thru a plist to get at info

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, plist

If I've got a plist set up like this

```
Key           Type         Value
Root          Array
 Item 0       Dictionary  
 -Title       String       Part One
 -Description String       Welcome to part one. Have fun
 Item 1       Dictionary  
 -Title       String       Part Two
 -Description String       Welcome to part two. Fun too.
 Item 2       Dictionary  
 -Title       String       Part Three
 -Description String       Welcome to part three. It's free
 Item 3       Dictionary  
 -Title       String       Part Four
 -Description String       It's part four. No more
```

How would I step thru to put all the titles in one array, and all the descriptions into another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oooooooo this is where the awesomeness of Key-Value Coding shines.

```
NSArray * plistContents = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathToPlist];
NSArray * titles = [plistContents valueForKey:@"Title"];
NSArray * descriptions = [plistContents valueForKey:@"Description"];
```

The secret here is that invoking `valueForKey:` on an array returns a new array of objects that contains the result of invoking `valueForKey:` on each thing in the array.  And invoking `valueForKey:` on a dictionary can be equivalent to using `objectForKey:` (if the key you're using is a key in a key-value pair).  For more info, see [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ).

One word of caution:  Using a key of "Description" can potentially cause you to tear some hair out when you start seeing weird results, because one misspelling and you'll actually start invoking the [`-description`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBAFEH) method on each dictionary (which is *not* what you want).

Comment: Dave DeLong rocks! I was seconds away from posting. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

See the [Collections Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i)

```
NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"items.plist"];
NSMutableArray *titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *descriptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
    [titles addObject:[item objectForKey:@"Title"]];
    [descriptions addObject:[item objectForKey:@"Description"]];
}

[items release];

// Do something with titles and descriptions

[titles release];
[descriptions release];
```